# jhipster - issue with custom relationship between two entities

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I m trying to create a relationship between two entities.
Entity Fournisseur(id,code,libelle)
Entity Catalogue (id, fournisseur_code)

I want the relationship between those two entities be between code and fournisseur_code.

I have modified the liquibase xml generated file for entity catalogue from

> ```
> <changeSet id="20150116113044" author="jhipster">
>     <createTable tableName="T_CATALOGUE">
>         <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
>             <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
>         </column>
>         <column name="fournisseur_id" type="bigint"/>
>         <column name="produit_id" type="bigint"/>
>         <column name="marque_id" type="bigint"/>
>         <column name="pays_id" type="bigint"/>
>         <column name="emballage_id" type="bigint"/>
>     </createTable>
>
>     <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="fournisseur_code"
>                              baseTableName="T_CATALOGUE"
>                              constraintName="fk_catalogue_fournisseur_id"
>                              referencedColumnNames="id"
>                              referencedTableName="T_FOURNISSEUR"/>
> ```

to

```
<changeSet id="20150116113044" author="jhipster">
    <createTable tableName="T_CATALOGUE">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="fournisseur_code" type="varchar(45)"/>
        <column name="produit_id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="marque_id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="pays_id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="emballage_id" type="bigint"/>
    </createTable>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="fournisseur_code"
                             baseTableName="T_CATALOGUE"
                             constraintName="fk_catalogue_fournisseur_code"
                             referencedColumnNames="code"
                             referencedTableName="T_FOURNISSEUR"/>
```

The table was well generated, but when I m trying to run the getAll function from CatalogueResource, it tells me :

> [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown
>   column 'catalogue0_.fournisseur_id' in 'field list'

I can't figure out why.
If someone knows....

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

the relation must be connected with the field.
you have to change:

```
baseColumnNames="fournisseur_code"
```

to this

```
baseColumnNames="fournisseur_id"
```